# parse query param by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in js which parse a url and creates a map of (paramName,value)

The code is like:

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
var data = {}
if(search!="")
{
    var urlParams = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}');
    for (var key in urlParams) {
        data[key] = urlParams[key];
    }
}
```

Now this is working fine for a plain url like
www.google.com?param1=2&param4=hello

But it is not working for a encrypted url like
www.google.com?param1=XDTY-300Hbc=&param4=hello

as here the **param1=XDTY-300Hbc=** contains a = in the end.
Please help

Comment: Just a side not you don't need to iterate over urlParams you can just use `data = JSON.parse(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var url = 'www.google.com?param1=XDTY-300Hbc=&param4=hello';
var query = url.substring(1);
var data = {};
query.split('&').filter(Boolean).forEach(function(pair) {
  pair = pair.split('=');
  data[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair.slice(1).join('=')).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
});
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: [Your answer has a lot of issues](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell).

Comment: Forget about decodeURIComponent

Comment: I would use  `var idx = pair.indexOf('=');` and `data[decodeURIComponent(pair.substr(0,idx))] = decodeURIComponent(pair.substr(idx+1));` instead of messing with arrays.

Comment: Also if there is no value there will not be an equals sign. In such a case pair will be equal to the key name and the value should be set to null.